# Find the last instance of a value in a row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm making a table to track projects by person and by task, sort of like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGTBr.png).

And I have a separate table that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdvP9.png).

Essentially, I'd like to write a formula in the 'Latest Task' column of the second table, that would find the last instance of the person's name for the given project, and return the task name.
So for this example, it would look up **ProjectB** in the first table, and find the last row with **Joe** (ROW 1) and return the task name (**Task1**).

In my research I came across this solution:

```
=MAX(
     INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(ADDRESS(MATCH([@Project],Table1[Project],0)+1,1),":",ADDRESS(MATCH([@Project],Table1[Project],0)+1,7)))=[@Person],
     COLUMN(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(ADDRESS(MATCH([@Project],Table1[Project],0)+1,1),":",ADDRESS(MATCH([@Project],Table1[Project],0)+1,7)))) -
     MIN(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(ADDRESS(MATCH([@Project],Table1[Project],0)+1,1),":",ADDRESS(MATCH([@Project],Table1[Project],0)+1,7)))))
```

But it doesn't seem to work and I'm clueless as to why not.

Any assistance is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

[image]

Formula in `K2`:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(INDEX(Table1[[Task1]:[Task6]],MATCH([@Project],Table1[Project],0),0)=[@Person]),Table1[[#Headers],[Task1]:[Task6]])
```

Comment: I checked (since im using a german Version) and its `#Headers`

Comment: Hej, thanks that seems to do the trick! If you've got a minute, I'd love to know _why_ that works :)

Comment: @AnžeOberčMrzel, `LOOKUP` is an array function where we try to lookup the value 2 in a boolean expression. Since that won't ocur it will return the nearest value which will be a 1. Then I used `INDEX` and `MATCH` for the correct data to be used. A hint is to test the formula in evaluation step by step and check what it actually does =)

Comment: @JvdV thanks! `LOOKUP` is one I haven't really used so I was confused by the `2, 1/` bit, the rest I'm familiar with. Always glad to learn something new

Comment: Also, it will return the **last** occurence of 1 =)

Answer (score 0):

this isn't the most pretty Formula, but it works. put this in the second Table Latest Task:

```
=INDEX(Table1[#Headers],AGGREGATE(14,6,COLUMN(INDEX(Table1[Project],MATCH([@Project],Table1[Project],0)):INDEX(Table1[Task6],MATCH([@Project],Table1[Project],0)))*([@Person]=INDEX(Table1[Project],MATCH([@Project],Table1[Project];0)):INDEX(Table1[Task6],MATCH([@Project],Table1[Project],0))),1)-1)
```